# Are there any GUI designer that makes easy cross platform between PC and mobile?

Tags: user-interface, cross-platform

I intent to create an application for PC (Linux/Windows/OSX) and mobile (Android/UbuntuTouch/iOS) worlds.

I know that there will be necessary different GUIs for PC and Mobile, although I want to know if there is one GUI designer that will enable me to create an interface for PC and for mobile.

I have read that Qt framework supports desktop and mobile, would it be the best option for me? I have some programming experience in C/C++, Lua, Python 2.x/3.x, C++ and HTML. However I never created an application with a GUI, just games, `plugins/extensions/scripts/addons`, and console apps.

Sorry for any misunderstandings, it is my first time making an application with a GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous cross-platform GUI tools (and frameworks), but two that spring to mind given your requirements are Qt and [Marmalade](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/sdk)

You probably want to download and try a couple out, as well as determine your budget, as these tools often have some cost for certain platforms or licensing constraints.

Comment: Perfect I was already thinking to go with Qt, and I will take a look at Marmalade too. Thanks.